# How are Python metaclasses different from regular class inheritance?

Tags: python, metaclass

This might be too much of an open ended question, but I'm just now learning about metaclasses in Python and I don't understand how a metaclass is any different than just having a child class inherit from the parent class, like

```
class child(parent):
```

Wouldn't this serve the same purpose of a metaclass?  I guess maybe I don't understand the purpose of a metaclass.

Comment: How is this a duplicate?  I'm not asking 'what is a metaclass', and I have read that thread a couple times.

Comment: I am specifically asking what is the difference between a metaclass and a child class inheriting from parent class, as stated in my question.

Comment: What you are asking is a subset of what is asked in that question, and if you read and understand the answer to that question, you'll understand the difference you're asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class AccessorType(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, d):
        type.__init__(self, name, bases, d)
        accessors = {}
        prefixs = ["get_", "set_", "del_"]

        for k in d.keys():
            v = getattr(self, k)
            for i in range(3):
                if k.startswith(prefixs[i]):
                    accessors.setdefault(k[4:], [None, None, None])[i] = v

        for name, (getter, setter, deler) in accessors.items():
            # create default behaviours for the property - if we leave
            # the getter as None we won't be able to getattr, etc..
            # [...] some code that implements the above comment
            setattr(self, name, property(getter, setter, deler, ""))
```

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that inheriting from a class does not affect how the *class* is created, it only affects how instances of the class are created.  If you do:

```
class A(object):
    # stuff

class B(A):
    # stuff
```

then A does not have any opportunity to "hook in" when B is created.  Methods of A may be called when an *instance* of B is created, but not when the class B itself is created.

Metaclasses allow you to define custom behavior for when a class is created.  Refer to the question I marked as duplicate for examples of how metaclasses work, and convince yourself that there are effects in those examples that you can't achieve with normal inheritance.

Comment: Try looking on youtube for a video tutorial, that may be more helpful.

Comment: @BrenBarn, thats the best one liner answer. Thanks !